# How to embed sounds from project library into a swf in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, embed, audio

When playing the .swf-file while it is in project's src directory all sounds are working because they're in the project's library directory. But when I copy the .swf-file to another directory and play it, it will be missing the sounds from the project's library. How can I "embed" the sounds into the .swf-file without making a class for each sound?